# Manipular dados .js com angular-cli

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

Olá!
Estou começando agora a mexer com angular e tenho um arquivo server.js que faz uma chamada no  banco de dados e trás os dados. Preciso ciar uma interface para exibir esses dados. A minha dúvida é: como consigo capturar os dados do arquivo .js e manipulá-los em um projeto angular-cli?

Desde já, agradecida.

Comment: Como esse arquivo faz a chamada?

Comment: Normalmente via uma requisição http. E padro da industria ter uma separação do front end e do backend.

Comment: Rebecca, precisamos entender melhor o seu problema, por favor inclua as partes onde o código é mais relevante,  e que possa nos ajudar a te ajudar, explique melhor o seu problema. Recomendo a leitura no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender melhor como funciona o site!

Answer (score -1):

Diego, usei o driver Ms SQL.
Eduardo, é uma aplicação muito simples, não queria separar. A consulta está ok, só queria pegar esses dados e exibir em uma interface.

Comment: Olá Rebecca, para responder comentários utilize a função comentários. O campo de respostas deve ser utilizado apenas para respostas para a pergunta em si.